# CSS styling for error messages

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a `div` which has `php` code to `echo` out errors on a page, I want to add some style to error appearance which is going well except one problem, every attribute works fine but `padding` seems to be their even when errors are not called I am using `javascript` to call errors though the error message is called only when their is some error but `padding` for error `div` is always there on the page. How to solve it out.

```
<div id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div><br />

<style>
#error {
font-size:
background-color:
opacity:
color:
padding:
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is correct and actually represents the situation you're describing.

Comment: yes it's just like that

Comment: Huh, it is? You don't declare *any* value for the properties, you're missing semi-colons after those (missing) values, and the `style` element is just floating below a `div` instead of in the `head` of your document.

Comment: when i say 'it is like that' i didn't mean without values stylesheet was just for giving idea how i have written it

Comment: We're strangers/volunteers without access to your context. When asking questions, it's important to create an actual repro that represents your scenario, because that makes it a lot easier for us to help you. See this help page for guidance on how to create a repro: [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

since your php code is embedded in your div tag , definitely whether the error is called or not does'nt matter. The padding will still be there. Apply the div within your php code, or just the padding css style in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling #error write css like this

```
#error {
font-size:
background-color:
opacity:
color:
padding:
display:none;
}
```

Now when you are call that #error then make css as

```
#error {
display:block;
}
```

Now it will not take any space if error message is not there